Python polars - how to aggregate dataframes
Objective
To efficiently aggreate the returned dataframes of a function in a Polars dataframe in Python.
Environment

Windows 10
Python 3.9.18
Polars 0.20.18

What I did so far
I want the equivalent of this code (this is a dummy code).
def dummy_dataframe(val):
    return pl.DataFrame(
        {
            "x": [va1 + 1, 0, 1],
            "y": [val + 2, 8, 9],
            "z": [val + 3, 5, 6],
        }
    )

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": ["a", "b", "a", "b"],
    }
)

groups = df.groupby('a').agg(pl.apply(exprs=['a'], function=lambda x: dummy_dataframe(x)).alias('result'))
results = []
for row in groups.iter_rows():
    group_name = row[0]
    group_val = row[1]
    df_ret = group_val.with_columns(pl.lit(group_name).alias('group_name'))
    results.append(df_ret)
df_results = pl.concat(results)
df_results

However, I believe iter_rows() is inefficient. This polars document says "Row iteration is not optimal as the underlying data is stored in columnar form; where possible." Since iter_rows() is not very efficient in Pandas I could imagine it's the same in Polars.
Research
Googling "polars dataframe in a cell" and "polars agg dataframe" and checking the first 10 pages of each didn't give me much information.
Conclusion
How do I efficiently aggreate the returned dataframes of a function?

You can store a struct e.g. pl.DataFrame().to_struct() - although using .apply is not optimal either. Perhaps if you explain what exactly you need to do - an "idiomatic" Polars approach could be given.

In your real-life example, does val actually alter the returned df for dummy_dataframe(val)? I mean: in the current example you just add the exact same df per group (i.e., the function input isn't used). If that is also true of your real-life example, that makes quite a difference.

Yes, it does. I changed the code.

The edit contains a typo va1 but the code itself also doesn't run. Can you share what you really need to do? Why pass GroupBy to an external function which returns a DataFrame? Can it be done with expressions? e.g. df.with_columns(result = pl.struct(x = pl.concat_list(pl.col("value") + 1, 0), y = pl.concat_list(pl.col("value") + 2, 8)).over("group")) which you can .unnest() and .explode()

Iterating through rows can be quite inefficient. I would suggest using group_by and map_groups in this case:
import polars as pl

def dummy_dataframe(val):
    return pl.DataFrame({
        "x": [val + 1, 0, 1],
        "y": [val + 2, 8, 9],
        "z": [val + 3, 5, 6],
    })

df = pl.DataFrame({"a": ["a", "b", "a", "b"]})

def process_group(df):
 
    group_name = df['a'][0]
    val = ord(group_name) - ord('a')
    result_df = dummy_dataframe(val)
    return result_df.with_columns(pl.lit(group_name).alias('group_name'))

df_results = df.group_by("a", maintain_order=True).map_groups(process_group)

print(df_results)


Which results in
shape: (6, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬────────────┐
│ x   ┆ y   ┆ z   ┆ group_name │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---        │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ str        │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ a          │
│ 0   ┆ 8   ┆ 5   ┆ a          │
│ 1   ┆ 9   ┆ 6   ┆ a          │
│ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ b          │
│ 0   ┆ 8   ┆ 5   ┆ b          │
│ 1   ┆ 9   ┆ 6   ┆ b          │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴────────────┘

